# Is creating new route from UI angular possible?

Tags: angular

For example; I have a component which is for user registeration and the demanded infos are name age and country.
When a user submit their infos on the page and complete registeration, I create a new user on my db.It's okay.

Let think about the user's name is Jacob. Is it possible to create new component and route like /users/jacob automatically after registeration? Or should I add new components and routes manually for sure?

Answer (score 2):

You should use routing parameters, probably with the id of the new user, then you will be provided with all the routes you could ever need.
You should then fetch data accordingly on route change or with a resolver, and populate your component wtih the data

```js
    export const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'users/:id', component: UserComponent}
    ];
```